# Conexão Dinâmica EF C# Windows Forms Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, app.config

estou com o seguinte problema:

O EF cria uma connectionString no app.config da aplicação e utiliza essa conexão sempre, mas caso precise mudar o servidor do banco eu terei que alterar o app.config.

Já tentei uma forma de fazer funcionar a troca do ip do servidor, mas quando executo o mesmo ele leva o & do símbolo &quote e fica da seguinte forma: &quote; ai quando inicio a aplicação automaticamente dá erro pois ele não reconhece as devidas informações. Segue o código do app.config e código que fiz via C# para alterar tal propriedade.

App.config

```
<connectionStrings>   
  <add name="ref_bdEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModeloDados.csdl|res://*/ModeloDados.ssdl|res://*/ModeloDados.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=master;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=ref_bd&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Código de alteração

```
string _ipservidor = string.Empty;
            _ipservidor = LerIni.LerINI(@"C:\Motion Software\bin\config.ini", "[IPServidor]");
            connectionString = "metadata=res://*/ModeloDados.csdl|res://*/ModeloDados.ssdl|res://*/ModeloDados.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server="+_ipservidor+";user id=sa;password=master;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=ref_bd&quot;";
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ref_bdEntities"].ConnectionString = connectionString;
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified); // Salva o que foi modificado
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings"); // Atualiza no app o bloco connectionStrings
            Properties.Settings.Default.Reload(); // Recarrega os dados de conexão
```

Me ajudem pfv. Estou utilizando o Mysql como banco e provavelmente irei utilizar uma hospedagem para o banco de dados (ignorem o fato de ser Windows forms).

Atualização - Estou usando Database First

Atualização 2 - O código acima não altera o valor do arquivo físico de config, quando coloco os arquivos necessários para funcionamento da aplicação e levo o arquivo de configurações Menu.exe.config (No caso o nome do exe é Menu) ele não altera esse arquivo e eu quero poder alterar esse arquivo, é possível?

Atualização 3 - No site http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/411013/Configuring-a-Connection-String-in-the-App-Config achei um exemplo que utiliza a alteração do xml no arquivo .config, pelo que pude perceber também ele utiliza de uma StringBuilder, a única parte do código que não entendi foi: `xElement.FirstChild.Attributes[2].Value = con;`, alguém pode me ajudar a entender? Estou quase chegando a uma solução só preciso de alguma ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de muita procura e analise consegui resolver o problema. Conforme descrito na atualização 3 eu achei um método de alterar o arquivo xml do app.config e coloco abaixo o código com a solução do problema:

```
public void Servidor()
        {
            string _ipservidor = string.Empty;
            _ipservidor = LerIni.LerINI(@"C:\Motion Software\bin\config.ini", "[IPServidor]");
            connectionString = "metadata=res://*/ModeloDados.csdl|res://*/ModeloDados.ssdl|res://*/ModeloDados.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string='server="+_ipservidor+";user id=sa;password=master;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=ref_bd'";
            updateConfigFile(connectionString);

            /* Altera app.config */
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ref_bdEntities"].ConnectionString = connectionString;
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified); // Salva o que foi modificado
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings"); // Atualiza no app o bloco connectionStrings
            Properties.Settings.Default.Reload(); // Recarrega os dados de conexão   

            /* Altera connection Entity Framework */
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder conEntity = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            conEntity.Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
            conEntity.ProviderConnectionString = "'server=" + _ipservidor + ";user id=sa;password=master;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=ref_bd'";
            conEntity.Metadata = "res://*/Modelo.csdl|res://*/Modelo.ssdl|res://*/Modelo.msl";
            ref_bdEntities BDEntidades = new ref_bdEntities(conEntity.ToString());
        }

        public void updateConfigFile(string con)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
            foreach (XmlElement xElement in xmlDoc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (xElement.Name == "connectionStrings")
                {
                    xElement.FirstChild.Attributes[1].Value = con;
                }

            }
            xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        }
```

Como podem perceber eu também fiz atualização pelo configuration e pelo EntityConnection. Isto foi só para ter certeza que iria funcionar, caso alguém ache que terá uma queda de desempenho me comunique por favor.

Mas o que acabou realmente com o meu problema foi alterar o valor do connectionString no xml do app.config, testei em uma pasta separada com o Menu.exe.config e funcionou.

O único problema que registrei é que como estava testando com o ip da maquina local 127.0.0.1, ao alterar somente o ultimo numero para qualquer outro ele continuava a conectar mas acho que isso ocorre por causa da porta 3306, mas ao colocar um ip diferente tipo 192.168.12.145 ele não acha a mesma porta então da erro de conexão.

Qualquer sugestão que vocês tiverem e quiserem compartilhar comigo, agradeço!

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, ao inicializar a aplicação eu faço uma pequena consulta na tabela de versão do meu sistema, se esta tentativa de consulta der erro, com certeza é problema de conectividade, assim, eu chamo um dialog para que o endereço seja setado e gravo :-)

```
        public static bool Configura(string strConecta, out string newStrConecta)
    {
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            ConnectionString = strConecta
        };
        newStrConecta = "";
        using (var bancoForm = new BancoForm())
        {
            bancoForm.tbServidor.Text = builder.DataSource;
            bancoForm.tbUsuario.Text = builder.UserID;
            bancoForm.tbPassword.Text = builder.Password;
            bancoForm.tbDatabase.Text = builder.InitialCatalog;
            var result = bancoForm.ShowDialog();
            if (result != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("\n\nFALHOU : " + strConecta + "\n\t");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                builder.DataSource = bancoForm.tbServidor.Text;
                builder.UserID = bancoForm.tbUsuario.Text;
                builder.Password = bancoForm.tbPassword.Text;
                builder.InitialCatalog = bancoForm.tbDatabase.Text;
                newStrConecta = builder.ConnectionString;
                Debug.WriteLine("\n\tSUCESSO !!! \n\t");
                Debug.WriteLine("Sucesso", newStrConecta);

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Funciona muito bem para mim. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]